# Visualize Vertical Velocity from VAD Profile in NetCDF Files in Python

Tags: python, netcdf

I am beginner trying to visulize weather data using archive NetCDF files.

My overall goal is to do azimuthal averaging (from full 360º radar scans) for radar reflectvity Z, and present the data in a Height vs Time format.

I believe to do this, I need to find the VAD Profile for vertical velocity. However, how do I take the NetCDF data to show this?

I have tried to get this data from Python, although I have only been able to figure out how to get the cover data from the NetCDF file.

I believe in my lack of knowledge I am missing some important steps on how to do this. So any help is appreciated. Thank you so much for your consideration and any help given. Any reccomended sources on how to get VAD Profiles from NetCDF files are also appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but it sounds like you’re asking both about a scientific method question and also some technical ones? I’d strongly recommend the xarray library for working with netCDFs, but you’re going to have to figure out the data manipulations you *want* before we can help you figure out how to execute them. You’ll also need to show us much more about what’s in your data before we can help. NetCDFs are used for everything from finance to astrophysics so we can’t just guess what you’re talking about :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.